# JoinColumn references a column, but the target entity has no property which maps to this column error in JPA/Hibernate SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have following entity classes in Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "branch_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Branch {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "branch_id")
    private String branchId;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("LOCAL")
public class LocalBranch extends Branch {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "division_head_id", referencedColumnName = "branch_id")
    private DivisionHead divisionHead;

    // other fields and mappings

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DIVISION")
public class DivisionHead extends Branch {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_head_id", referencedColumnName = "branch_id")
    private RegionHead regionHead;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "divisionHead", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<LocalBranch> localBranches = new HashSet<>();

    // other fields and mappings

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REGION")
public class RegionHead extends Branch {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "circle_head_id", referencedColumnName = "branch_id")
    private CircleHead circleHead;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "regionHead", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<DivisionHead> divisions = new HashSet<>();

    // other fields and mappings

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CIRCLE")
public class CircleHead extends Branch {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "circleHead", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<RegionHead> regions = new HashSet<>();

    // other fields and mappings

    // getters and setters
}
```

If I start the application, I am getting A '@JoinColumn' references a column named 'branch_id' but the target entity divisionHead.RegionHead has no property which maps to this column.

I don't understand why Hibernate/Jpa can't see `branch_id` column in entity classes even though they are extending from Branch class which has unique column `branch_id`.

If I don't provide any referencedColumnName then it's working fine. But, I need foreign key reference to `branch_id` column. I try changing the referencedColumnName = 'branchId' (field name), but it didn't work as well (as expected).

How to get out of this error. Is ther any issues with associations of my entity classes. As They are self referncing associations, I doubt something is not right?

Comment: Why don't you reference the ID? The primary key is the id

Comment: I need to query the table based on branch_id of DivisionHead or RegionHead. If branch_id is the foreign key then I don't need to get the id for the given branch_id before querying the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just especially for you, I opened an issue:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16501

and fixed it. You'll need to wait for Hibernate 6.3.

Comment: How can I get it to test with my code

Comment: Well you could pull the `main` branch of hibernate-orm and build it.

Comment: @GavinKing facing this error with 6.4.2.Final

Comment: same, I also have same problem with hibernate-core 6.4.1.final